# Equivalente de .test() (js) no php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

No JavaScript, temos  a função **[`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**, por exemplo:

```
/Test \[(\d+)\]/gi.test(string); // Pode retornar true ou false.
```

O php possui alguma função semelhante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim. No `PHP` você pode utilizar o **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)**

```
if ( preg_match("/[\d]+/", $value) ) {
   /* Code Here */
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. É isso mesmo. :)